# [Tkinter]I can't insert text into a Text widget when I use 'place' method to place it, and I also can't edit it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# frame = Frame(root, height = 300, width = 500)
text = Text(root,width = 15)

# frame.pack()
# text.pack()
text.insert(END,'testwsetsetsetsets')
text.place(rely = 0, relx = 0.5, anchor = 'center')

mainloop()
```

[image]

There should be a text, but it din't, and I also can't edit it.I can't iuput any word into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the combination of options `rely=0` and `anchor='center'`. The center of your text widget is at the top of your window so you cannot see the top half (including the inserted text).

To fix it use

```
text.place(rely=0, relx=0.5, anchor='n')
```

to put the top of your text widget at the top of the window instead.

To avoid this kind of issue, you can use `grid` or `pack` instead of `place`.